# Case-sensitive query - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I rewrite as Latest Developer a record which was created as LATEST DEVELOPER via SQL query?

Comment: Any SELECTs or comparisons involved? is this a one off request? if not, what does your data look like generally?

Comment: I'm with @gbn. Can you clarify what exactly you are trying to do? Do you just want to update a value to have a different case? How are you going to query this data (does that even matter to you)? Please edit your question with the answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET YourColumn = 'Latest Developer'
WHERE YourColumn COLLATE LATIN1_GENERAL_CS_AS = 'LATEST DEVELOPER'
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you want to convert strings to "Title Case" - in which case you can [write a udf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/230138/sql-server-make-all-upper-case-to-proper-case-title-case/230224#230224) to do this and use it in an `update` statement.

Comment: Also http://sqlblogcasts.com/blogs/tonyrogerson/archive/2006/06/20/832.aspx